# NSError, __autoreleasing and blocks

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
    __block BOOL isPaidFeed = NO;

    [[MyManager sharedInstance].tempAddedFeeds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [[MyManager sharedInstance] addSource:obj toPage:pageTitle error:&error];
        if(error){
            *stop = YES;
        }

    }];
```

However it gives me an error that I am using __autoreleasing in a block. How do I fix this issue? Not use an enumerator?

Comment: How about using __weak or __unsafe_unretained if you just want to make sure that the block does not retain the object.

Comment: In this case I'd keep it strong. It's a Foundation class, not one whose use would generally risk a retain loop.

Comment: But why should you create a strong reference, if you are just creating NSError object within some method.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the declaration of `error` inside of the block.